# Why FEM electric analysis gives only access to current density?

Tags: computational-physics, comsol, electromagnetism

A Comsol study using frequency sweep on electric current physics yields only current density as accessible variables.

I understand the underlying equation used is Ohm's law, i.e.

$$\mathbf{J} = \sigma  \mathbf{E}$$

where $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field, $\mathbf{J}$ is the current density, and $\sigma$ is the conductivity.

Why is it that they do not implement $V = R I$ directly.

What is the computational difficulty in its implementation ?

Comment: They represent different models, the first equation describes a continuum model, where you have a value of current density and electric field. This model would let you analyze what is happening inside your domain. In the second model you have a lumped version, i.e., a [mascrocopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm's_law#Other_versions) version of it. A model where you are considering the overall behavior of your system and not the internal details. Since Comsol uses FEM... I suppose that is natural to expect the first version, although you can obtain things like the current by integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are saying the same thing, at a fundamental level - it's just that the implementation is a bit different. The first equation you noted is valid throughout the system because it solves for the *intrinsic* values throughout the system, such as the local current density and local electric potential.

The second equation you mentioned is a lumped-value equation, that is technically valid throughout the system, but by the way you wrote it, I'm guessing that $\mathbf{V}$, $\mathbf{R}$, and $\mathbf{I}$ have units of voltage ($V$), resistance ($\Omega$), and current ($I$), respectively. The question is then, voltage where? Current where? Resistance where?

When modeling a continuum physics problem it's beneficial to reduce everything into its intrinsic properties instead of extrinsic properties, which means that you end up working with scale-independent quantities.

Now back to your first equation:

$$ \mathbf{J} = \sigma \mathbf{E} $$ is the same as $$ \mathbf{E} = \frac{1}{\sigma} \mathbf{J} $$

It's good to remember that conductivity ($\sigma$, with units Siemens/meter) is just the reciprocal of resistivity ($\rho$), which has units of $\Omega \cdot m$. Thus

$$ \mathbf{E} = \rho \mathbf{J} $$

This is more or less the valid *local* equation that an FEM solver would solve at each node in the problem domain, and which most resembles your *global* equation of Ohm's law.

For a more comprehensive answer to how resistivity relates to conductivity, resistance, and conductance, check out the wiki article on exactly this topic:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity